# Modal - central alignment on Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, modal-dialog

I'm currently building a Modal pop-up for my new website, however, try as I might, I can't get the Modal box to appear centrally (both horizontally & vertically) on my mobile. It works great on Desktop, but is way off to the right on my mobile.

Can someone help?

Here is my **JSFiddle** where you can find my CSS, HTML & Javscript ::
http://jsfiddle.net/1ytv3yc0/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns text-center">
        <a href="#modal_contact" class="button center large-text full big-pad modal-trigger"  onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Modals', 'Open Form', 'Work with us']);">Work with us and find out</a>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="content">

    <div class="modal medium" id="modal_contact">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>

</section>
```

Many thanks for any guidance :-)

Comment: I can't really replicate your problem in the Fiddle. With far off to the right, do you mean it only appears half on your screen? Does it break out of the viewport?

Comment: Hi @Tim - yes, it breaks out of the viewport, if you visit http://jsfiddle.net/1ytv3yc0/embedded/result/ on your mobile, you'll be able to see it a little better

Comment: I can't find anything that forces the width to exceed the viewport so much as it does now. Did you set the viewport? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Hi @Tim - yep, I set it to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`

Comment: Hey @Tim - see my answer - woop! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a vendor prefix issue.
Adding `-webkit-transform` below my `transform` declaration fixed this issue :-)